# How can I create custom grid columns?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Is there a way to create a custom implemation of a grid column?

I don't want to create a wrapper or something like that, it should be class/component inherited from the kendo-grid-column. Is this already possible with the beta or is it planed for one of the coming release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<kendo-grid-column>` component is just a container for settings, and even if it is extended, the grid component will not pick it up.

If you need to render custom content in a given column header and cells, you can achieve that via the header and cell templates, as [shown in the documentation](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/#columns).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.

The company I work also had some projects with the Kendo controls for WPF. There we create custom implementation of grid columns, not just a template, because sometimes it's to much programming for just add it in a template or we need other data then you have it from the template context. Another problem is, a custom implemantion would reduce the code in the grid, for exmaple if you need the same special column in 10 different grids, it would be maybe just a open/close tag. Can we at least share the template at the moment? We always add the component template in a separate file and add it with templateUrl.

Do you already know, if this is the "final" answer or is Telerik adding this functionality to the release version?

Comment: This is not something that we have planned or investigated so far. Please post it as a suggestion in our UserVoice feedback portal - http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/555517-kendo-ui-for-angular-2-feedback. We will look into that further in case it gets more attention.